# How do I combine rewrites (use a subdirectory as root while forcing https and non-www)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How does one combine .htaccess rewrites to achieve the following:

- Users visiting the root of a domain (example.com), should see and navigate the content of a subdirectory (example.com/subdirectory).
- https and non-www should be forced.

This works for using the subdirectory as root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
```

Questions:

- Should I add the other two rules (force https and non-www) between "RewriteEngine On" and the first RewriteCond?
- Does every rule use the original request or is the original request modified with each rule?

Comment: 1. yes 2. request_uri may be modified with each rule

Comment: @anubhava Thank you. With "may be modified with each rule", do you mean that the request is only modified if the rewrite conditions are all true? Are there instances where the request_uri is modified even though the rewrite conditions for the rule are all true??

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. If a rule is successful then it may modify REQUEST_URI as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ subdirectory/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory/$1 [L]
```

Usage = These rules will make all urls to https, non-www and if someone visit example.com it will redirect to example.com/subdirectory.